# Where Can I Update price of a variant which reflects in the front end automatically in aspdotnetstorefront

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to change/update the price of a variant of generic product in aspdotnetstorefront,
but I fount that it is not reflecting in the front end.Can anyone please let me know where can I change the price?

Answer (score 0):

Update the price from mange product section in the admin. Select any product then click show variant, again select any default variant. now in the main tab, change the price in price textbox and save and close it.  Now Reset the cache. Check the frontend to see new price [image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are updating the price directly in SQL as if you were updating it through the Admin UI, you would see the change.  If that is the case, all you need to do is reset the Cache using the button int eh top right hand corners of the admin screen (you can also reset the App Pool, but this may cause a slowness to your end customers).